# Geometric meaning of prime elements?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

This question is motivated by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63899/what-does-it-mean-geometrically-that-an-element-in-a-domain-is-irreducible), which seeks geometric meaning for irreducibility of an element. The first sentence is:

> Consider a domain A and a non-zero element $f\in A$. That element $f$ is prime if and only if the subscheme $V(f)\subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is integral and this is a completely satisfactory geometric interpretation of primeness.

I don't understand how to think of integral domains geometrically at all. What is the geometric intuition for primeness of an element?

Comment: integral = irreducible + reduced

Comment: How much background do you have? Have you heard of schemes?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer I have heard of them but I have only seen the definition. I think Hoot's answer is actually all there to it - I just need to familiarize myself with the geometric meaning of reducedness. The only question is whether to delete this question or not.

Comment: From your previous questions I assume you know a bit about algebraic geometry. You can think geometrically of an integral domain $A$ as a ring of "functions" on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. To add a bit to Hoot's comment: since $A$ is domain it follows immediately that it is reduced, and $V(f)$ is irreducible for every prime $f \in A$ (e.g. see [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ER)).